# Rails 3.1 + Heroku: Can someone help me decipher this Heroku log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I'm experiencing this intermittent issue where my client is receiving multiple JSON responses from (I think) a single HTTP request to my Rails server on Heroku. Here's the Heroku log showing the issue...

```
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/games/2/call" for 76.171.181.11 at 2012-04-19 17:22:27 -0700
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by GamesController#call as */*
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"fb_id"=>"0", "id"=>"2"}
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 163ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 93.3ms)
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4594ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /games/2/call] invalidate, pass
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4546ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4594ms status=200 bytes=2012
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4570ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4560ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4534ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 560 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 560 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 539 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.231.155 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.231.155 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.32.38 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 108.70.74.121 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19"
```

I'm new to Rails and Heroku, so I can't quite understand this log enough to figure out what's happening.  Is my Rails app on Heroku receiving multiple HTTP requests from my client, or is it only receiving one HTTP request and returning multiple JSON responses?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's getting 7 POST requests at the same time:

```
# First Request, heroku starts to process it normally
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/games/2/call" for 76.171.181.11 at 2012-04-19 17:22:27 -0700
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by GamesController#call as */*
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"fb_id"=>"0", "id"=>"2"}

# First request returns OK
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 163ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 93.3ms)

# Second request starts
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4594ms status=200 bytes=2013

# It looks like the second request fails
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /games/2/call] invalidate, pass

# Request 3-7 come in
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4546ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4594ms status=200 bytes=2012
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4570ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4560ms status=200 bytes=2013
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.heroku.com/games/2/call dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4534ms status=200 bytes=2013

# Heroku responds to the requests... though I'm  not sure what it's serving up.
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 560 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 560 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 76.171.181.11 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 539 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.231.155 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.231.155 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 207.151.32.38 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19" myapp.heroku.com
2012-04-20T00:22:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 108.70.74.121 - - [20/Apr/2012:00:22:27 +0000] "POST /games/2/call HTTP/1.1" 200 540 "http://myapp.heroku.com/pages/fb/webplayer_64.unity3d" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19"
```

I've had issues like this occasionally -- Javascript requests that bubble up the DOM and fire multiple times when I only meant them to fire once. This can crash a server pretty fast, so you should definitely look at your app and make sure you're not rapid-fire triggering AJAX calls.

A really easy way to catch this is to put an `alert()` immediately before or after any ajax call and see how many times it fires vs. how many you expect it to.

I don't know if that's your problem, but I've had that kind of thing happen to me before.

Comment: you can also use `console.log('AJAX FIRED');` and use something like inspector in chrome or safari or firebug in firefox. If you're using jQuery check out the delegate method rather than binding directly using an element, it's saved me a number of times.